# Can't bind to 'formGroup' in Angular

Tags: angular

My Issue is:
I am trying to make what should be a very simple form in my Angular application, but no matter what, it never works.

Why am I getting that error? Am I missing something?

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninComponent,
    SignupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports:[
    SigninComponent,
    SignupComponent
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.scss']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  signinForm:any;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signinForm = new FormGroup({
      email : new FormControl(''),
      password : new FormControl('')
    })

  }
}
```

**login HTML**

```
<form class="longin" [formGroup]="signinForm">
          <label for="email" class="">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value="" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter your email id">
          <label for="password" class="">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: what is your error ? at first you should set FormGroup for  type of   signinForm

Comment: should be declare: `signinForm:FormGroup;`. NOTE: you can try use a *ngIf: `<form *ngIf="signinForm" class="longin" [formGroup]="signinForm">` to avoid initial errors

Comment: I have try this but same error. login.component.ts file add ```signinForm!:FormGroup```

Comment: Are you import your login.module in the main.module? You code seems ok. NOTE: I imagine when you wrote login html really is the "signin.component.html" NOTE2: **remove** the "value" in your input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form builder to create a form.

```
  basicForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.basicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email : new FormControl(''),
      password : new FormControl('')
   })
 }
onFormSubmit(){
 const value =this.basicForm.value;
}
```

In HTML

```
<form class="longin" [formGroup]="signinForm">
          <label for="email" class="">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value="" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter your email id">
          <label for="password" class="">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
          <button (click)=onFormSubmit() class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: why mixed formBuilder and the constructor of FormControl???

Comment: The FormBuilder service has three methods: control(), group(), and array(). These are factory methods for generating instances in your component classes including form controls, form groups, and form arrays. we use the group method to create the basicForm controls.

Comment: that's, you use new FormControl() instead this.formBuilder.control()